# New user and database on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005, and I tried to create a new database with a user.

I used these commands with sa user on master db:

```
CREATE LOGIN mobstat WITH PASSWORD = 'mobstat123';    
CREATE USER mobstat FOR LOGIN mobstat;
CREATE SCHEMA mobstat AUTHORIZATION mobstat;
CREATE DATABASE mobstat COLLATE SQL_Hungarian_CP1250_CI_AS;
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'mobstat';
```

Every command executed well, but I cannot login with the new user.
The error is:

> Cannot open database "mobstat" requested by the login. The login failed.

I've tried to Google it, but no result yet.
My client is DBeaver.

Comment: Users and schemas are database objects.  You created them before you created the `mobstat` database, so they're most likely in the wrong db (master, perhaps?).  Find those, drop them, then re-create them in the `mobstat` db.

Comment: Why did you create a user, schema and role membership in master? Create the login, create the database, then change your context to that database. In the new database, create the user, schema and role.

Comment: Because I'm a newbie in DBA :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE LOGIN mobstat WITH PASSWORD = 'mobstat123';    
GO
CREATE DATABASE mobstat COLLATE SQL_Hungarian_CP1250_CI_AS;
GO

-- You were creating a schema and a User before you have created a database
USE [mobstat]
GO
CREATE USER mobstat FOR LOGIN mobstat;
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'mobstat';
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [mobstat] AUTHORIZATION [mobstat]
GO
```